# MySQL get next 3 months of holidays by month, day (regardless of year)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of holidays, stored by date, so they have a year:

```
Christmas        2014-12-25
Birthday         2014-05-12
Holiday 3        2015-11-27
```

Let's say today is November 1st, in the year 2020. How do I retrieve the holidays for the next three months, in order of month, day occurrence? So the record set should look like:

```
Holiday 3        2015-11-27
Christmas        2014-12-25
```

EDIT: If I modified the table to include the months and dates in separate columns, a suggested by PressingOnAlways below, how could I query for the date range?

```
Holiday          Year        Month      Date
Christmas        2014        12         25
Birthday         2014        05         12
Holiday 3        2015        11         27
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) See [about Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: Not all holidays are on the same day every year. Many of them are based on the layout of the month (e.g, Mother's Day is on the second Sunday in May), and some are even more complicated (e.g, Easter and some other religious holidays). As such, there's no way to use the data you have in the way you're asking for!

Comment: Duskwuff is correct, this will only work for something like birthdays or static month/day holidays.

Comment: Okay, I've modified the example.

Comment: For anyone interested, I wrote a UDF in MS-SQL to dynamically compute holidays for any given year.  I've never converted it to mySQL, but it is available at http://www.joebooth-consulting.com/sqlServer/sqlServer.html#CalendFunc if anyone would like to convert it and use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can select holidays using DAY() and MONTH() methods of SQL
In your where clause use DAY(holiday) AND MONTH(holiday)
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_day

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92c97/15

Comment: For second sunday in may you can get entries in may that match DAYNAME(holiday)='Sunday' and choose the second date

Comment: @corey, this actually is probably a better answer than mine.

Comment: Great, Thanks! This looks good! My only other question is how do I put them in order of occurrence? Meaning Thanksgiving is listed before Christmas?

Comment: You can try adding "ORDER BY MONTH(holiday)"

Comment: @TaimourTanveer I don't think that'll work, because of wrapping. If there's a holiday in 12 (December) and then 1 (January), they'll be in the wrong order.

Comment: This query though a bit complex solves the problem http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92c97/15